# Why the coordinates of mouse in canvas are wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I intend to draw free with the mouse cursor in canvas. My code seems to do the part with color but it doesn't take the exact coordinates of my current mouse position in canvas when i draw.

```
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style=" width: 400; height: 400px; background-color:yellow; position: absolute; margin-left:100px; margin-top:30px"></canvas>
<script>

var Color = 'blue';

var Canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var Context = Canvas.getContext('2d');
$("canvas").on("mousemove",function(e){
        X = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        Y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
Context.strokeStyle = Color;
    Context.lineWidth = 3;
    Context.lineCap = 'round';
    Context.beginPath();
Context.moveTo(X,Y);
Context.lineTo(X,Y);
Context.fillRect(X,Y, 3,3)
Context.stroke();
Context.closePath();
});
</script>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93L8mLnf/

I tested in `console.log` the coordinates and they are corect. I'm confused..

Comment: don't set canvas width and height through CSS, use its `.width` and `.height` properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to synchronize the dimension of the canvas with the DOM element.
Add this:

```
Canvas.width = Canvas.clientWidth;
Canvas.height = Canvas.clientHeight;
```

[Demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/L0xw7n28/)

You'll also notice the canvas isn't blurred anymore.

Note that this must be done every time the canvas DOM element changes size (usually because the window is resized) so when your element isn't of fixed size you should bind an event handler on the window `resize` event to do that synchronization again (and usually to redraw the content).

Comment: I see , now it works perfect! Thank you for showing me how to do it. :d

Answer (score 1):

You have to add width and height by canvas attributes
[see in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eduardochenrique/dym11wpa/)

```
<canvas id="canvas" style="background-color:yellow;" width="250" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: indeed, by adding width and height not through style, it works how it should. This is weird for me as a novice to understand deeply why it acts like this..

Comment: Most often this isn't a solution, because you lose the power of CSS for sizing the canvas. IMO this answer is bad practice.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, this is arguable. Your solution does only work for canvases already appended and rendered in doc, not for buffer canvas.